# way to open .rar files in Ubuntu

Tags: sound, software-installation

I am very new to Ubuntu and trying to install some soundfonts. One of them is in .rar. Do any of you know a way to open this type of fiel and make it operational?

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: I thought that Ubuntu natively supported RAR files.

Comment: Ah, maybe not...

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and do:

```
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
```

If the installation for `p7zip-rar` fails make sure that you have the multiverse repository enabled and try again. When this is done you should be able to unpack `.rar` archives with the archive manager or if you want to do it in terminal:

```
7z x archive.rar
```